# Change image layout or wrap in DOCX with Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

I paste image into docx programmatically. But in result the layout does not suit me. Faced a lack of documentation.
I need to change image wrap (layout). For example now I have this:

[image]

But want this:

[image]

**UPD1**: What I do: iterate through the paragraphs, then through the runs and find certain run with special bookmark. In this run I add picture:

```
XWPFPicture pic =  run.addPicture(
        new ByteArrayInputStream(picSource),
        Document.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG,
        "pic",
        Units.toEMU(100),
        Units.toEMU(30));
```

**UPD2**: Investigated something interesting inside this class:

```
org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.wordprocessingDrawing.CTAnchor
```

method `setWrapTight(CTWrapTight var1)`. May be is it. By still don't know how to apply it to my code.

**UPD3**: Finally I came to this (currentRun - run with our picture):

```
    CTWrapTight ctWrapTight = currentRun.getCTR().getDrawingList().get(0).addNewAnchor().addNewWrapTight();
 CTWrapPath ctWrapPath = ctWrapTight.addNewWrapPolygon();

 CTPoint2D ctStart = ctWrapPath.addNewStart();
 ctStart.setX(0L);
 ctStart.setY(0L);

 CTPoint2D ctLineTo1 = ctWrapPath.addNewLineTo();
 CTPoint2D ctLineTo2 = ctWrapPath.addNewLineTo();
 CTPoint2D ctLineTo3 = ctWrapPath.addNewLineTo();

 ctLineTo1.setX(21384L);
 ctLineTo1.setY(20520L);

 ctLineTo2.setX(21384L);
 ctLineTo2.setY(0L);

 ctLineTo3.setX(0L);
 ctLineTo3.setY(0L);

ctWrapTight.setWrapText(STWrapText.BOTH_SIDES);
```

But it's break down document when I try to open it:

> We're sorry. We can't open document because we found a problem with
>   its contents.

Dependency are:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: "But I still don't know how to apply it to my code.": In that one line of code? This is not possible. You will need much more code then. Show a complete example of how you are adding the picture in line with text. Then I will show you how to add  a picture having text wrap.

Comment: @AxelRichter I've updated question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While you already found the right classes to use - [CTAnchor](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/wordprocessingDrawing/CTAnchor.java) and successors - there is also the need considering the [XML Schema definition of  anchor](http://www.ecma-international.org/news/TC45_current_work/Office%20Open%20XML%20Part%204%20-%20Markup%20Language%20Reference.pdf#page=3906&zoom=auto,85.6,250). And this states there are many more duty elements required than only the ones which are defining wrapping. So using class by class of  `org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006` you are probably coding page wise code. My preferred solution for such problems is providing `XML` having all needed elements updated by some variables. This `XML` then can be parsed to get the needed object.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.util.Units;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTDrawing;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTGraphicalObject;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.wordprocessingDrawing.CTAnchor;

public class WordInsertPictures {

 private static CTAnchor getAnchorWithGraphic(CTGraphicalObject graphicalobject, 
                                              String drawingDescr, int width, int height,
                                              int left, int top) throws Exception {

  String anchorXML = 
   "<wp:anchor xmlns:wp=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing\" "
  +"simplePos=\"0\" relativeHeight=\"0\" behindDoc=\"1\" locked=\"0\" layoutInCell=\"1\" allowOverlap=\"1\">"
  +"<wp:simplePos x=\"0\" y=\"0\"/>"
  +"<wp:positionH relativeFrom=\"column\"><wp:posOffset>"+left+"</wp:posOffset></wp:positionH>"
  +"<wp:positionV relativeFrom=\"paragraph\"><wp:posOffset>"+top+"</wp:posOffset></wp:positionV>"
  +"<wp:extent cx=\""+width+"\" cy=\""+height+"\"/>"
  +"<wp:effectExtent l=\"0\" t=\"0\" r=\"0\" b=\"0\"/>"
  +"<wp:wrapTight wrapText=\"bothSides\">"
  +"<wp:wrapPolygon edited=\"0\">"
  +"<wp:start x=\"0\" y=\"0\"/>"
  +"<wp:lineTo x=\"0\" y=\"21600\"/>" //Square polygon 21600 x 21600 leads to wrap points in fully width x height
  +"<wp:lineTo x=\"21600\" y=\"21600\"/>"// Why? I don't know. Try & error ;-).
  +"<wp:lineTo x=\"21600\" y=\"0\"/>"
  +"<wp:lineTo x=\"0\" y=\"0\"/>"
  +"</wp:wrapPolygon>"
  +"</wp:wrapTight>"
  +"<wp:docPr id=\"1\" name=\"Drawing 0\" descr=\""+drawingDescr+"\"/><wp:cNvGraphicFramePr/>"
  +"</wp:anchor>";

  CTDrawing drawing = CTDrawing.Factory.parse(anchorXML);
  CTAnchor anchor = drawing.getAnchorArray(0);
  anchor.setGraphic(graphicalobject);
  return anchor;  
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();

  run.setText("The picture in line: ");

  InputStream in = new FileInputStream("samplePict.jpeg");
  run.addPicture(in, Document.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG, "samplePict.jpeg", Units.toEMU(100), Units.toEMU(30));
  in.close();  

  run.setText(" text after the picture.");

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  run = paragraph.createRun();
  in = new FileInputStream("samplePict.jpeg");
  run.addPicture(in, Document.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG, "samplePict.jpeg", Units.toEMU(100), Units.toEMU(30));
  in.close();  
  CTDrawing drawing = run.getCTR().getDrawingArray(0);
  CTGraphicalObject graphicalobject = drawing.getInlineArray(0).getGraphic();
  CTAnchor anchor = getAnchorWithGraphic(graphicalobject, "samplePict.jpeg", 
                                         Units.toEMU(100), Units.toEMU(30), 
                                         Units.toEMU(30), Units.toEMU(0));
  drawing.setAnchorArray(new CTAnchor[]{anchor});
  drawing.removeInline(0);

  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("The previous picture is anchored wrapTight. The previous picture is anchored wrapTight. The previous picture is anchored wrapTight. The previous picture is anchored wrapTight. The previous picture is anchored wrapTight. The previous picture is anchored wrapTight.");

  document.write(new FileOutputStream("WordInsertPictures.docx"));
  document.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your varian, I'll surely try this after my vocation. But now I found temporary solution. I added `break` before make `.addPicture()`, and image layout became the needed. But with break before it.

Comment: @Optio: Your question was about changing layout options from "In Line with Text" to "With Text Wrapping - Tight". This definitely cannot reached by adding line break before the picture run.

Comment: As I said - it is temporary solution. But without this - heigh of the image equal heigh of the line (run). Adding some breakes before somehow helped. I did not said it right at first comment -  of course layout doesn't changed, but it visually produces the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you use NPOI in C#, you can write code like below:

var imageRun = paragraph.CreateRun();

using (FileStream picData = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
imageRun.AddPicture(picData, (int)NPOI.XWPF.UserModel.PictureType.PNG, imagePath, Units.ToEMU(100), Units.ToEMU(100));

```
CT_Drawing drawing = imageRun.GetCTR().GetDrawingList().First();
CT_GraphicalObject graphicalobject = drawing.GetInlineArray(0).graphic;

//Replace the newly inserted picture, add CTAnchor, set floating attribute, delete inline attribute
CT_Anchor anchor = getAnchorWithGraphic(graphicalobject, "Seal",
                             Units.ToEMU(120), Units.ToEMU(120),
                             Units.ToEMU(50), Units.ToEMU(-80), true);
drawing.anchor = new List<CT_Anchor>() { anchor };//Add floating attribute
drawing.inline.RemoveAt(0);//R
```

}

static CT_Anchor GetAnchorWithGraphic(CT_GraphicalObject ctGraphicalObject,
String deskFileName, int width, int height,
int leftOffset, int topOffset, bool behind)
{

```
String anchorXML =
        "<wp:anchor xmlns:wp=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing\" "
                + "simplePos=\"0\" relativeHeight=\"1\" behindDoc=\"" + ((behind) ? 1 : 0) + "\" locked=\"0\" layoutInCell=\"1\" allowOverlap=\"1\">"
                + "<wp:simplePos x=\"0\" y=\"0\"/>"
                + "<wp:positionH relativeFrom=\"page\">"
                + "<wp:posOffset>" + leftOffset + "</wp:posOffset>"
                + "</wp:positionH>"
                + "<wp:positionV relativeFrom=\"paragraph\">"
                + "<wp:posOffset>" + topOffset + "</wp:posOffset>" +
                "</wp:positionV>"
                + "<wp:extent cx=\"" + width + "\" cy=\"" + height + "\"/>"
                + "<wp:effectExtent l=\"0\" t=\"0\" r=\"0\" b=\"0\"/>"
                + "<wp:wrapNone/>"
                + "<wp:docPr id=\"1\" name=\"Drawing 0\" descr=\"" + deskFileName + "\"/><wp:cNvGraphicFramePr/>"
                + "</wp:anchor>";

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(anchorXML);
CT_Drawing drawing = CT_Drawing.Parse(xmlDoc, XWPFPictureData.NamespaceManager);
CT_Anchor anchor = drawing.GetAnchorList().First();
anchor.graphic = ctGraphicalObject;
return anchor;
```

}

Comment: Pardon me, but how does an answer using NPOI and written in C# help someone who is using [Apache] POI and Java?