# Meaning and unit of `x` and `y` in Office Open XML `wrapPolygon`

Tags: ms-word, apache-poi, openxml

Does someone knows what is the meaning and unit of `x` and `y` in Office Open XML `wrapPolygon`?

The [documentation](http://www.ecma-international.org/news/TC45_current_work/Office%20Open%20XML%20Part%204%20-%20Markup%20Language%20Reference.pdf#page=3927) states:

"Specifies a coordinate on the x-axis. The origin point for this coordinate shall be specified by the parent XML element. ...The possible values for this attribute are defined by the ST_Coordinate simple type (§ 5.1.12.16)."

That sounds like it should be describing a polygon starting at `x`=0 and `y`=0 in top left point of the picture. And the unit would be `EMU`.

But this cannot be true because if used in the code [Change image layout or wrap in DOCX with Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47673133/change-image-layout-or-wrap-in-docx-with-apache-poi/47716625#47716625), then, if I do something like:

```
...
  +"<wp:wrapTight wrapText=\"bothSides\">"
  +"<wp:wrapPolygon edited=\"0\">"
  +"<wp:start x=\"0\" y=\"0\"/>"
  +"<wp:lineTo x=\"0\" y=\""+height+"\"/>"
  +"<wp:lineTo x=\""+width+"\" y=\""+height+"\"/>"
  +"<wp:lineTo x=\""+width+"\" y=\"0\"/>"
  +"<wp:lineTo x=\"0\" y=\"0\"/>"
  +"</wp:wrapPolygon>"
  +"</wp:wrapTight>"
...
```

then the resulting wrap points are much far outside the picture.

Instead describing a square polygon 21600 x 21600

```
...
  +"<wp:wrapPolygon edited=\"0\">"
  +"<wp:start x=\"0\" y=\"0\"/>"
  +"<wp:lineTo x=\"0\" y=\"21600\"/>"
  +"<wp:lineTo x=\"21600\" y=\"21600\"/>"
  +"<wp:lineTo x=\"21600\" y=\"0\"/>"
  +"<wp:lineTo x=\"0\" y=\"0\"/>"
  +"</wp:wrapPolygon>"
...
```

leads to wrap points which are in fully width x height of the picture.

[image]

And this is independent of the pictures size itself. It may be a square or rectangle sized picture in all possible sizes.

So while "The origin point for this coordinate shall be specified by the parent XML element." and the polygon starts at `x`=0 and `y`=0 in top left point of the picture, the unit cannot be `EMU` as for width and height. And since a square polygon 21600 x 21600 leads to rectangle wrap points if the picture is a rectangle, even the meaning of the polygon itself is not clear.

Is this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Well, seems nobody answers. So I will at least providing an example for why this rule: "A square polygon 21600 x 21600 leads to wrap points in fully width x height independent of picture size." could be useful.

If the need is setting more complex wrap points, a ellipse for example, only depicting this ellipse to a square 21600 x 21600 is needed, independent of picture size. This is much more simple than calculating the wrap points dependent on the really picture size. So we can forcing `Word` having really wrapping text tight around the picture.

Example Code:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.util.Units;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTDrawing;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTGraphicalObject;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.wordprocessingDrawing.CTAnchor;

public class WordPicturesWrapTight {

 private static CTAnchor getAnchorWithGraphic(CTGraphicalObject graphicalobject, 
                                              String drawingDescr, int width, int height,
                                              int left, int top) throws Exception {

  String anchorXML = 
   "<wp:anchor xmlns:wp=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing\" "
  +"simplePos=\"0\" relativeHeight=\"0\" behindDoc=\"1\" locked=\"0\" layoutInCell=\"1\" allowOverlap=\"1\">"
  +"<wp:simplePos x=\"0\" y=\"0\"/>"
  +"<wp:positionH relativeFrom=\"column\"><wp:posOffset>"+left+"</wp:posOffset></wp:positionH>"
  +"<wp:positionV relativeFrom=\"paragraph\"><wp:posOffset>"+top+"</wp:posOffset></wp:positionV>"
  +"<wp:extent cx=\""+width+"\" cy=\""+height+"\"/>"
  +"<wp:effectExtent l=\"0\" t=\"0\" r=\"0\" b=\"0\"/>"
  +"<wp:wrapTight wrapText=\"bothSides\">"
  +"<wp:wrapPolygon edited=\"1\">"; //Set edited 1, so Word will not destroying the wrap points.

  //A square polygon 21600 x 21600 leads to wrap points in fully width x height independent of picture size.
  //So if the need is setting more complex wrap points, a ellipse for example, only depicting this ellipse 
  //to a square 21600 x 21600 is needed independent of picture size.

  long[] x = new long[5];
  long[] y = new long[5];
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   x[i] = i * 2700L; //2700 = 21600/2/4
   y[i] = Math.round(Math.sqrt(116640000d - Math.pow(i * 2700d, 2d))); //116640000 = (21600/2)^2
  }

  anchorXML += "<wp:start x=\""+(x[0]+10800)+"\" y=\""+(10800-y[0])+"\"/>";

  for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
   anchorXML += "<wp:lineTo x=\""+(x[i]+10800)+"\" y=\""+(10800-y[i])+"\"/>";
  }
  for (int i = 3; i > -1; i--) {
   anchorXML += "<wp:lineTo x=\""+(x[i]+10800)+"\" y=\""+(10800+y[i])+"\"/>";
  }
  for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
   anchorXML += "<wp:lineTo x=\""+(10800-x[i])+"\" y=\""+(10800+y[i])+"\"/>";
  }
  for (int i = 3; i > -1; i--) {
   anchorXML += "<wp:lineTo x=\""+(10800-x[i])+"\" y=\""+(10800-y[i])+"\"/>";
  }

  anchorXML += "</wp:wrapPolygon>"
  +"</wp:wrapTight>"
  +"<wp:docPr id=\"1\" name=\"Drawing 0\" descr=\""+drawingDescr+"\"/><wp:cNvGraphicFramePr/>"
  +"</wp:anchor>";

  CTDrawing drawing = CTDrawing.Factory.parse(anchorXML);
  CTAnchor anchor = drawing.getAnchorArray(0);
  anchor.setGraphic(graphicalobject);
  return anchor;  
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();

  InputStream in = new FileInputStream("ellipticSample.png");
  run.addPicture(in, Document.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, "ellipticSample.png", Units.toEMU(100), Units.toEMU(60));
  in.close();  
  CTDrawing drawing = run.getCTR().getDrawingArray(0);
  CTGraphicalObject graphicalobject = drawing.getInlineArray(0).getGraphic();
  CTAnchor anchor = getAnchorWithGraphic(graphicalobject, "ellipticSample.png", 
                                         Units.toEMU(100), Units.toEMU(60), 
                                         Units.toEMU(100), Units.toEMU(16));
  drawing.setAnchorArray(new CTAnchor[]{anchor});
  drawing.removeInline(0);

  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("The picture is anchored wrap tight. This means text will wrap this according to a polygon described by wrap points. Seems a square polygon 21600 x 21600 leads to wrap points in fully width x height independent of picture size. So if the need is setting more complex wrap points, a ellipse for example, only depicting this ellipse to a square 21600 x 21600 is needed independent of the picture size. This is much more simple if more complex wrap points shall be set. But it's a shame, that this feature not seems documented. So can we rely on it or not?");

  document.write(new FileOutputStream("WordPicturesWrapTight.docx"));
  document.close();
 }
}
```

Result:

[image]