# Text Wrapping using Apache POI

Tags: java, netbeans, apache-poi

How can I set the added picture's text wrapping?

```
r.addPicture(new FileInputStream(img1), 
             imgFormat1, 
             imgFile1, 
             Units.toEMU(220), 
             Units.toEMU(180)
);
```

Is it possible? setting the text wrapping like tight, behind text, square, etc.?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47673133/change-image-layout-or-wrap-in-docx-with-apache-poi/47716625#47716625 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47717419/meaning-and-unit-of-x-and-y-in-office-open-xml-wrappolygon/48354855#48354855

Comment: i tried the code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47673133/change-image-layout-or-wrap-in-docx-with-apache-poi/47716625#47716625 It seems to work fine but when I open the document, the picture's text wrapping is the same