# Wrap Text in Apache POI(docx)?

Tags: java, apache-poi

[image]
I want to add an image into docx , but I just found simple apache poi code:

```
 XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument()
        XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph()
        XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun()
        run.addPicture(new FileInputStream(img), format, img, Units.toEMU(width), Units.toEMU(height))
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(doc)
        document.write(outputStream)
```

Now I want to set the picture in front of text , but I can not found any reference.

Comment: That's a good question and it is interesting how difficult is to find any resources on internet related to this. I tried to search but have not found anything. `XWPFRun` seems to have only simple text formatting. The closest I found is this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47673133/2886891 - but it is soooo an ugly solution :)

Comment: @Honza Zidek: I am curious how a more less ugly solution would look like. Can we hope you will providing a such sooner or later?

Comment: @AxelRichter: Nope unless I need it for my project :) I am not blaming *you* for providing an ugly solution, I am blaming POI for not providing an API for achieving the same goal without need to hack the XML.

Comment: @Honza Zidek: "without need to hack the XML": Well `Office Open **XML**` is the new file format for `Microsoft Office`. And answers here, at least my answers, are never thought to be ready-to-use productive code but to be minimal working examples showing the principles. Of course in productive code this should be done more flexible and less based on fixed XML strings. But, as said in my answer, when using class by class of `org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006` you are probably coding page wise code. Not applicable for an answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Office Open XML` formats and also `*.docx` as such are `ZIP` archives containing `XML` files and other files in a directory structure. So if we are curious we can simple unzip them and taking a look into.

Using the default code for adding a picture to a text run in `/word/document.xml` we find something like:

```
<w:r>
 <w:t>Picture inline with text:</w:t>
 <w:drawing>
  <wp:inline distT="0" distR="0" distB="0" distL="0">
   <wp:extent cx="1905000" cy="254000"/>
   <wp:docPr id="0" name="Drawing 0" descr="samplePict.jpeg"/>
   <a:graphic>
    <a:graphicData ...
```

If we are opening this usig `Word` and changing the text wrap of the picture to behind text, then in `/word/document.xml` we find something like:

```
<w:r>
 <w:drawing>
  <wp:anchor allowOverlap="1" behindDoc="1" layoutInCell="1" locked="0" relativeHeight="0" simplePos="0">
   <wp:simplePos x="0" y="0"/>
   <wp:positionH relativeFrom="column"><wp:posOffset>0</wp:posOffset></wp:positionH>
   <wp:positionV relativeFrom="paragraph"><wp:posOffset>0</wp:posOffset></wp:positionV>
   <wp:extent cx="1905000" cy="508000"/>
   <wp:effectExtent b="0" l="0" r="0" t="0"/><wp:wrapNone/>
   <wp:docPr descr="samplePict.jpeg" id="1" name="Drawing 0"/><wp:cNvGraphicFramePr/>
   <a:graphic>
    <a:graphicData ...
```

As you see, the first is within an `wp:inline` element while the second is within an `wp:anchor` element.

Unfortunately the `wp:anchor` element cannot be applied using `apache poi` until now. So we need to know where to find the low level objects, `apache poi` bases on. I found [http://grepcode.com](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/CTDrawing.java) a good reference.

Now we can coding the needed things based on those low level objects:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.util.Units;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTDrawing;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTGraphicalObject;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.wordprocessingDrawing.CTAnchor;

public class CreateWordImagesBehindAndInFrontText {

 private static CTAnchor getAnchorWithGraphic(CTDrawing drawing /*inline drawing*/ , 
  String drawingDescr, boolean behind) throws Exception {

  CTGraphicalObject graphicalobject = drawing.getInlineArray(0).getGraphic();
  long width = drawing.getInlineArray(0).getExtent().getCx();
  long height = drawing.getInlineArray(0).getExtent().getCy();

  String anchorXML = 
   "<wp:anchor xmlns:wp=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing\" "
  +"simplePos=\"0\" relativeHeight=\"0\" behindDoc=\""+((behind)?1:0)+"\" locked=\"0\" layoutInCell=\"1\" allowOverlap=\"1\">"
  +"<wp:simplePos x=\"0\" y=\"0\"/>"
  +"<wp:positionH relativeFrom=\"column\"><wp:posOffset>0</wp:posOffset></wp:positionH>"
  +"<wp:positionV relativeFrom=\"paragraph\"><wp:posOffset>0</wp:posOffset></wp:positionV>"
  +"<wp:extent cx=\""+width+"\" cy=\""+height+"\"/>"
  +"<wp:effectExtent l=\"0\" t=\"0\" r=\"0\" b=\"0\"/><wp:wrapNone/>"
  +"<wp:docPr id=\"1\" name=\"Drawing 0\" descr=\""+drawingDescr+"\"/><wp:cNvGraphicFramePr/>"
  +"</wp:anchor>";

  drawing = CTDrawing.Factory.parse(anchorXML);
  CTAnchor anchor = drawing.getAnchorArray(0);
  anchor.setGraphic(graphicalobject);
  return anchor;  
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument doc= new XWPFDocument();
  XWPFParagraph paragraph;
  XWPFRun run; 
  InputStream in;
  CTDrawing drawing;
  CTAnchor anchor;

  //default
  paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Picture inline with text:");
  in = new FileInputStream("samplePict.jpeg");
  run.addPicture(in, Document.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG, "samplePict.jpeg", Units.toEMU(150), Units.toEMU(40));
  in.close();  

  paragraph = doc.createParagraph();

  //behind text
  paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  in = new FileInputStream("samplePict.jpeg");
  run.addPicture(in, Document.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG, "samplePict.jpeg", Units.toEMU(150), Units.toEMU(40));
  in.close();  
  drawing = run.getCTR().getDrawingArray(0);

  anchor = getAnchorWithGraphic(drawing, "samplePict.jpeg", true /*behind text*/);

  drawing.setAnchorArray(new CTAnchor[]{anchor});
  drawing.removeInline(0);
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("The above picture is behind the text. ");

  paragraph = doc.createParagraph();

  //in front of text
  paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  in = new FileInputStream("samplePict.jpeg");
  run.addPicture(in, Document.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG, "samplePict.jpeg", Units.toEMU(150), Units.toEMU(40));
  in.close();  
  drawing = run.getCTR().getDrawingArray(0);

  anchor = getAnchorWithGraphic(drawing, "samplePict.jpeg", false /*not behind text*/);

  drawing.setAnchorArray(new CTAnchor[]{anchor});
  drawing.removeInline(0);
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("The above picture is in front of the text. ");

  paragraph = doc.createParagraph();

  doc.write(new FileOutputStream("CreateWordImagesBehindAndInFrontText.docx"));
  doc.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer. BUT - Office Open XML is the 11-years-old file format for MS Word and the wrap text has been in MS Word also for quite a long time and it is an important feature, nothing very special. So the fact that the only way of achieving this formatting in POI is via hacking XML (here by *hacking* I simply mean too-low level access) is a shame of the POI library.

Comment: @Honza Zidek: Well someone has to do the ugly low level things. And even if the library you are using would doing this internally and hidden, you would have to know about those things also. Users of programming libraries are not the same kind of users as application users are but are programmers. They are responsible for their software product in whole. That includes used libraries, except there are contracts having warranty provisions between the producer of the library and you, the programmer who uses it. I doubt you will have a such with `apache poi` ;-).

Comment: What does it change on the fact that POI is missing high-level API for a common things which you need to do in MS Word? And I have always understood that the main purpose of an API is to add an extra abstraction layer so the users of the API would not have to care about the implementation details. So shame on Apache POI for not having done their task sufficiently :) (taking into account that the *picture wrap options* feature is not anything very special from the user's point of view).